# How to string parse into hashmap using java language

Tags: java, string, dictionary, hashmap

I have a string but cannot parse it into Map

`string s="sakib hasan : 3 : sumon ali : 4 : tutul : 100`

I need to create a `HashMap` from above string. `sakib hasan,sumon ali,tutul,shila akter` should be KEY of `HashMap` and `3,4,100,1,` should be `VALUE`s of `KEY`s.

I have tried with the flowing code but unable to solve the problem

```
Map<String, Integer>amap=new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 
String[] splt=s.split(":");
for (String string : splt)  
{ 
  String[] pair=string.split(" ");
  amap.put(pair[0])+Integer.parseInt(pair[1]);  
}
```

Is there a way can I do this without hard coding

Comment: Try using your debugger and stepping through the code. You will be able to see the value of `string` in each iteration and it should help you solve this problem, as well as other problems you may encounter in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least,I got the answer

```
Map<String, Integer>amap=new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 
String[] splt=s.split(":");
try {
    for (int i = 0; i <= pair.length; i +=2) {
    amap.put(pair[i].trim(), Integer.parseInt(pair[(1 + i)].trim()));
}
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this.
Your split on ":" will return each item individually.

Then you just have to take each group as a set of two which you can account for in the for loop with `i+=2`

```
Map < String, Integer > amap = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
String[] splt = s.split(" : ");
for (int i = 0; i < splt.length; i += 2) {
    amap.put(splt[i],Integer.parseInt(splt[i + 1]));
}
```

Comment: I completely failed with those compilation errors heh. Everything should be fixed now

Comment: Would the Integer you're putting into the map have to be trimmed of white space for parsing?

Comment: As Drew mentioned, I would add `.trim()` to the `split[]` and `splt[]` values

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that @DrewKennedy I fixed it in the answer

Comment: Should compile now with no issues. An alternative would be to split at ` : ` (pad the colon). :)

Comment: I like that idea better actually heh

Comment: I have a query to yours if it is two or more line string which i read from file then what will happen.such as string storage in file one line --> sakib hasan : 3 : sumon ali : 4 : tutul :,secondline..> 100 : shila akter : 1

Comment: Could the second line contain part of the pair from the first line? Such as first line containing "shila akter" second line ": 4"?

Comment: I am sorry @austinwernli you are correct,but just add the for loop within try-catch block. have to use trim() method thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your for loop is going through each element that you split and every single time, adding the hashmap only index 0 & 1. You need to increment the indices.

```
    String s = "sakib hasan : 3 : sumon ali : 4 : tutul : 100 : shila akter : 1";

    Map<String, Integer> amap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] splt = s.split(":");
    for(int i = 1; i < splt.length;i+=2)
        amap.put(splt[i-1].trim(), Integer.parseInt(splt[i].trim()));
```

Comment: Done this way, starting at 1, this will ensure that the put method will never be called on the last oddball element if it's an odd number of element for some reason. Also splitting at just the colon & trimming later ensures that if your string has a delimiter of "__:_" or something like that instead of "_:_", it won't trip up on this.

Comment: I have a query to yours if it is two or more line string which i read from file then what will happen.such as string storage in file one line --> sakib hasan : 3 : sumon ali : 4 : tutul :,secondline..> 100 : shila akter : 1

Comment: That's going to be an issue in either implementation here, You're going to have to either concatenate the string before hand, or once the next line is read in call an intermediate put on the one in between. If you're reading from a file though, something like a Scanner will probably work a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar solution using streams instead of a for loop:

```
IntStream.range(0, splt.length / 2)
    .forEach(i -> map.put(splt[i], Integer.parseInt(splt[i + 1]));
```

Or you could turn the .forEach into a collector that creates the map.